# Found: 'java.util.Date', required: 'com.google.api.client.util.DateTime' GAE

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, datetime, objectify

I have writing backend for Google App Engine

```
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Index;
import java.util.Date;
@Entity
public class DeviceData {

    /**
     * Unique identifier of this Entity in the database.
     */
    @Id
    private Long key;

    @Index
    private UserDevice device;
    public Date date;
     //getters and setters
}
```

And the endpoint is like

```
    @ApiMethod(httpMethod = "POST")
    public final DeviceData updateDeviceData(UserDevice device,@Named("date") Date date, User user) throws ServiceException {
            DeviceData newDeviceLocation = new DeviceData();
            newDeviceLocation.setDevice(device);
            newDeviceLocation.setLatitude(latitude);
            newDeviceLocation.setLongitude(longitude);
            newDeviceLocation.setDate(date);
            OfyService.ofy().save().entity(newDeviceLocation).now();
            return newDeviceLocation;
    }
```

But when I try to call it from my android App like

```
deviceLocatorApi.devicedata().updateDeviceData(new Date(), userDevice).execute();
```

it gives following error

> Found: 'java.util.Date', required: 'com.google.api.client.util.DateTime' more..
>   Error:(49, 45) error: method updateDeviceData in class DeviceLocator.Devicedata cannot be applied to given types;
>   required: DateTime,UserDevice
>   found: Date,UserDevice
>   reason: actual argument Date cannot be converted to DateTime by method invocation conversion

I did a workspace level search and I could not find `DateTime` class anywhere. So where is this coming from. Also how did argument order change here i.e first argument should have been of type UserDevice and 2nd of type Date?

Comment: From which `jar` are you accessing the `DeviceData.java` ?

Comment: Did not get you. I am using studio and have added GAE module in my android app. Dependencies are automatically handled.

Comment: Could you just check if the `updateDeviceData` method is overloaded? If so, you might be using the wrong signature.

Comment: It is not. There are only 2 methods in endpoint - `public final DeviceData updateDeviceData(UserDevice device, @Named("date") Date date, User user) throws ServiceException` and `public final DeviceData listDevicesData(UserDevice device, User user) throws ServiceException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check if you have gdata-core.jar present under your project class path. This class is present under the said jar only. and instead of passing new java.util.Date() as parameter add the below code.

```
deviceLocatorApi.devicedata().updateDeviceData(new DateTime(new java.util.Date()), userDevice).execute();
```

check this [link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api.client/google-api-client-util/1.2.3-alpha) for jar. Check the version as per your requirement.

hope this helps!

Comment: Yes I have used `deviceLocatorApi.devicedata().updateDeviceData(new DateTime(new java.util.Date()), userDevice).execute();` for now. But not sure if it will work. And anyways question is how did method signature change? And I dont see the jar you have mentioned `gdata-core.jar` in classpath.

Comment: Oops! my mistake the jar name would be similar to google-api-client-util-x.x.x.jar. And this must work

Comment: Also being a service call the order of the arguments are not fixed rather the data type is considered for resolving the arguments, so that should not be an issue.

Comment: Yup that worked but I am still wondering how did the argument type changed from `Date` to `DateTime`.

Comment: Did you changed the version of the GoogleApis. I am not sure on this point but it might happen that it would have changed with an upgrade to the api.

Comment: Nope did not change anything. Anyway accepting this as it solved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @ Vivek Singh any idea how to convert DateTime back to Date?

Comment: use the getValue() function this method returns the long representation of date. Use the links for more information on the api support [DateTime](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/util/DateTime), [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)